# Apart from ontologies, which other methods for knowledge representation are there in Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: reference-request, knowledge-representation, expert-systems, ontology

From what I have been reading, I see statements like

> Ontology is a common method used for knowledge representation in
> artificial intelligence.

But there is never really a discussion around what other options are available. To allow me to research other options I am hoping someone could maybe suggest alternatives?

As an extra question, do you have a preference for a particular system? If so, why?